# How do I disable Android @IntDef annotation checks in special cases?

Tags: android, casting, annotations, android-support-library, suppress

One such case is reading an int from a Bundle and storing it into the variable restricted by @IndDef annotation:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@IntDef({STATE_IDLE, STATE_PLAYING, STATE_RECORDING})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface State {}

public static final int STATE_IDLE = 0;
public static final int STATE_PLAYING = 1;
public static final int STATE_RECORDING = 2;

@MainActivity.State int fPlayerState = STATE_IDLE;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        fPlayerState = savedInstanceState.getInt(BUNDLE_STATE); //Causes "Must be one of: ..." error
```

There must be some way of suppressing the check or casting from int to @MainActivity.State int in order to set the variable in the last line.

The other case is to write a negative test that calls a function with annotated parameter intentionally passing the wrong parameter in order to test that the Exception is thrown in such case. There must be a way to suppress annotation check in order to compile such test.

Answer (score 52):

I've found the way to suppress the annotation checks. Actually, there are three of them:

1. Add `@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")` before the definition of your class. In my case:

   ```
   @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Add `@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")` before the definition of your method. In my case:

   ```
   @Override
   @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
   }
   ```

These two approaches do not work for me, because I want annotation checks on all of my code, except for just one statement.

3. To suppress a check on a single line add a specially formatted comment (!!!).

   ```
   //noinspection ResourceType
   fState = savedInstanceState.getInt(BUNDLE_STATE);
   ```

Comment: Wouldn't a type safe way to get an `@IntDef` back out of a bundle be to do a switch on it and assign the final result based on the values? e.g. "`state = getInt(); switch (state) case 1: fState = STATE_IDLE ...`"  The down side is that it moves the verification from compile time to run-time, which was the whole point of `@IntDef` to begin with. (The result isn't particularly maintainable, either, if you add values frequently. )  You could also do a secondary lookup table to mimic the result of "Enum.values()".

Answer (score 5):

```
@Status int state1=bundle.getInt(STATE_ELEMENT1);
setStatus1(state1);
//instead of direct setStatus1(bundle.getInt(STATE_ELEMENT1);
```

Comment: I guess this does not check whether the value is valid, so use only if you know it must be a @Status in your case. upvoted though, especially since OP asked to not be bothered by the warning