# How to add custom system service name to @ServiceName StringDef?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lint

In some of our Activities, we've overridden `getSystemService()` method to return some custom objects for custom service names. It works well for us, to pass down some object to a View somewhere deep inside such Activity.

But in Android Studio we get an error generated by a lint inspection in a line that gets our custom system service:

`return (CustomService) context.getSystemService(SERVICE_NAME);`

I know lint uses a `@ServiceName` annotation on `getSystemService()` which is defined via a `@StringDef` in `Context` class. I would like to know how I can extend this definition to include our custom service names.

I wouldn't like to turn of this very usefull inspection nor suppress this error every time we use our custom system service. That's why I hope it is possible to add custom names for lint to recognize that this call is correct.

Comment: If editing Context.java is not an option (i.e., you're not building a custom ROM) then there's nothing you can do apart from maybe suppressing the error somehow -- [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27474142/507761) might do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SomeClass{

    public static final String SERVICE_1= "SERVICE_1";
    public static final String SERVICE_2= "SERVICE_2";
    public static final String SERVICE_3= "SERVICE_1";

    @StringDef({SERVICE_1, SERVICE_2, SERVICE_3})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface ServiceName{}

    ...

    public Object getService(@ServiceName String name){
        //Resolve service by string name
        ...
    }

}
```

to use @StringDef annotation add following dependencies to gradle build file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
}
```

For more info use [Support Annotations](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations)